# How to specify "issues count" when searching repositories in Github Search

Tags: github, open-source, github-issues, github-search

When searching for repositories, I can use the "help-wanted-issues" and "good-first-issues" search qualifiers to narrow down the search results like so.

`react in:topics,readme language:javascript help-wanted-issues:>0`

But I want to specify issues count when searching repositories regardless of their labels because not all issues are labeled with the labels I mentioned above. e.g,

`react in:topics,description language:javascript issues:>0`

I know that there are separate qualifiers to search for issues but I don't want to search for any specific issue, I want to search for repositories according to my search query which contains number of issues that I can specify. Is there any workaround?

I read the docs [here](https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/searching-on-github/searching-for-repositories) and expected to find some search qualifier (other than "good-first-issues" and "help-wanted-issues") to specify number of issues in a repository.